# Query base with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, angular

> Querybase takes in a Firebase Database Reference and an array of fields you wish to index on. When you create new records it will automatically handle the generation of keys that allow for multiple querying. The caveat is that it only supports straight equivalence (no less than or greater than).

I am beginner to firebase creating chat app using ionic 2 with firebase

How to retrieve Query with Multiple child using firebase

I refer this link

https://github.com/davideast/Querybase

```
import Querybase from 'querybase';
const databaseRef =firebase.database().ref('/chats');
const querybaseRef = Querybase.ref(databaseRef, ['sender', 'receiver']);
```

This is my code and run the project getting this err

> polyfills.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined

How to fix this issue

Kindly advice me,

Thanks & regards

Comment: Sounds like you haven't required the library. Before calling `querybase.ref(...)` you need to `const querybase = require('querybase');`

Comment: I already import querybase " import Querybase from 'querybase'";

Comment: Show us your code...! And point out the line the error is referring to.

Comment: import Querybase from 'querybase';

 const databaseRef =firebase.database().ref('/chats');
 const querybaseRef = Querybase.ref(databaseRef, ['sender', 'receiver']);
                                                                                                                This is my code and run the project getting this err                               polyfills.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined

Comment: @chris G how to import the necessary things after running npm.command for querybase in angular?